# How to create contour Heat-map: MAPBOX

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to create contour heat-maps using data driven styling mapbox. (only based on data point magnitude)

I am using heat map layer and it looks something like this: 
[image: created using heat map layer]

I want to create something like this (Done using Matlab):
[image: contour heat map]

Is it possible using map box? Any ideas to do this would be very helpful. The closest I could get was using heat map layer, and after trying different combinations of weight, intensity and radius still could not achieve anything better than the image below.

Comment: Can you describe more specifically what your data is and the visualisation you want to produce? It's a bit hard to interpret just from two images what it should do.

Comment: yes.. I want to show the pH values of a point in water and my data point are in a path. The density is high on that path and is affecting the visualisation, whereas only the pH values should be affecting. 
Where pH is high it should be red, like in the second picture, and where the pH is low it should be blue. 

I want to interpolate the data for the areas where there is no data point.

I implemented heat maps from mapbox, but it considers point density and hence looks like the first picture. 

And I still Havant been able to find a solution.

Comment: Ok, I think what you're looking for analysis which is beyond what a visualisation library like Mapbox-GL-JS can do. You'll need to prepare your data offline using R or MatLab or whatever first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to confirm, do you mean I should generate images using R or Matlab offline and overlay them on the maps?

Comment: I prepared my data in python in the backend by creating a meshgrid and filling it using interpolation. Then, I passed it to the template and used Mapbox library for the visualization